# S3 show image size as 0 KB Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload the image to s3 via kotlin android. I have successfully connected to my bucket and the image is also getting stored in the bucket but the size of the image shown is 0KB and when I try to open the url it shows nothing. I have searched the web each and everything but no success yet.

Please see the below code and help me out.

```
fun uploadtos3(context:Context, file:File) {
        if (file != null)
        {
            val credentialsProvider = CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context,
                    poolId, // Identity Pool ID
                    Regions.AP_SOUTH_1 // Region
            )
            val s3 = AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider)
            val transferUtility = TransferUtility(s3, context)
            val observer = transferUtility.upload(
                    buketName, //this is the bucket name on S3
                    file.getName(),
                    file,
                    CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead //to make the file public
            )
            observer.setTransferListener(object:TransferListener {
                override fun onStateChanged(id:Int, state:TransferState) {
                    if (state.equals(TransferState.COMPLETED))
                    {}
                    else if (state.equals(TransferState.FAILED))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
                override fun onProgressChanged(id:Int, bytesCurrent:Long, bytesTotal:Long) {
                    var percentage:Int = ((bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100).toInt())
                    Log.e("Status", "Percentage" + percentage)
                }
                override fun onError(id:Int, ex:Exception) {
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

[image: Refer the image in s3 bucket which says 0KB]

TIA